# How to have a simple list of words, but one word be a different color?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to get just one of them to be of a different color.

```css
#red li {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="red">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your style selector is wrong. it should be `#red { color: red; }`

Comment: `#red li` would match a `li` that is *within* an element with the ID `red`. You probably wanted `li#red`, the `li` that *has* the ID red, or (given that an ID is very specific) just `#red`.

Comment: thanks for explaining it a little bit more...and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Here you go.

```css
li#red{
  color: red;  
}

OR

#red{
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="red">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

There are many ways to target an element in DOM using CSS.

Commonly used are:

`#` used when target element has an `id` attribute.

`.` used when target element has a `class` name.

You can target an element directly as well. But there may be many elements of same type.

In your case there is exactly one `<li>` element with an `id`. So to target that you can use `li#id{property: value}` or simply #id{property: value} since `ids` are highly specific and unique.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you've changed, and *why*.

Comment: li in front is not really necessary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: you mean change from your comment ? I was composing the answer when you commented. Should i delete it ?

Comment: No, I mean changed **in the code**, to make it work. Give the OP an *explanation*, so they can actually learn something.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the html style tag.

```html
<ul>
  <li style="color:red">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li#red{
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="red">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

```css
/*If you like to change just text color not bullet, please try the following one:*/

li #red{
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="red">Coffee</span></li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```